# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String .Model.Users.getPhone()' on a null object reference

Tags: java

I am getting an error in logcat but it doesn't show in my code. When I try to switch between different activities, it forgets the current online user and hence it crashes.

Here is my code

```
private void checkCartList() {

  DatabaseReference cartsR;
  cartsR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List")
    .child("User View")
    .child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getPhone());


  cartsR.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtmsg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtmsg1.setText("");
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what you have is a differently logged version of a NullPointerException.

Comment: thanks for your comment,could you please elaborate more

Comment: you are calling an instance member on a non-instantiated field.

Comment: Thank you its finally working